# How can I analyse the influence of a binary variable on a set of pre- and post-survey Likert scale questions?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert

I've analysed the unpaired survey responses using the Mann-Whitney U test and several questions show a change after treatment at p < 0.05. However I would now like to characterise the influence of a binary demographic variable (captured in the survey) on the results. Is it acceptable to split the survey results by the variable and analyse them separately? If so, how would I determine whether the variable was statistically significant? If not, what would be a good approach here?